# Consumer is not consuming : UnknownMemberIdException occurs and rebalance is keep on failing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

For a specific topic session time out occurred once which triggered UnknownMemberIdException
now even though there is no session timeout UnknownMemberIdException occurrs repeatedly  and rejoin is keep on failing with the same exception.

I tried this article https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-394:+Require+member.id+for+initial+join+group+request cant find any solution

also increased session.timeout to 6 mins still issue not resolved